# VPS, VPN and traffic forwarding

Tags: networking, server, vpn, iptables

I've configured a VPN server using [OCServer](http://ocserv.gitlab.io/www/index.html) on my VPS and I'm using anyconnect to connect successfully to the VPS from a client. I want all my traffic to be sent using my vps so I've configured IPV4 traffic forwarding and tried some iptables settings but even though I'm connected to the server my traffic isn't sent from the tunnel I've created.
How can I forward all my traffic from the VPS so that when I lookup my IP I see the VPS's IP?

Comment: Do you setup `nat` for traffic from client and do you enable ip forwarding on server?

Comment: I do, but not sure if it is working. I configured NAT and ip forwarding but not working. How can I be sure if it is configured correctly?

Comment: I've tried tcpdump also and apparently traffic is being sent to the vps from my client but not responding back.

Comment: Cna you please give us output from command `traceroute 8.8.8.8` executed on client when you are connected to vpn?

Comment: that doesn't give you much info on how we are connected since i'm behind a firewall I get no reply and anyway traffic from my port 80 needs to be forwarded which isn't.

Comment: `traceroute` will give me path, but ok.

Comment: can you cive me output from command `sudo ifconfig` or `sudo ip a`

Comment: Does it have to be `OCServer`, or can you switch to something like `OpenVPN`?

Comment: Would I be able to use anyconnect with openvpn?

Comment: @Farzan did you have a look at my answer below?

Comment: @yosefrow I did, it did help a lot but that wasn't exactly the case I went through the config file and found some problems there

Comment: Ok glad u fixed. Maybe include ur answer so other ppl with the same problem can learn 

Answer (score 2):

Let's try to solve this.

I guess that your `vpn` server have `tunX` interface and all `vpn client` are  connect to this interface.

Set traffic forwarding on server.
This is done either by using

```
 echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

After that

add a rule telling to forward the traffic

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tunX -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tunX -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Because you router/firewall do not known for network on you vpn lan on interface `tunX` we must do `masquarade` for trafic from `vpn clents` to internet, with ip address from interface `eth0`

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

On this way traffic from `tunX` can go to rest of the network through `eth0`.

Answer (score 1):

While ip forwarding is useful for getting clients *behind* a gateway to talk through your computer and reach *your* default gateway, I dont think it will solve your issue alone.

What you want is *all* traffic that is not local, to be handled by a specific ip/computer. This is the very definition of what a default gateway does. It handles *all* traffic not handled by the local network.

Therefore you must make sure that all interfaces *except* for the interface through which you are connected to the VPS (probably tun0 or something similar) have a default gateway of 0.0.0.0 (basically no default gateway defined if you are using a gui, which means they are simply sent back into the network)

Then you define the default gateway of 0.0.0.0 to be handled by your VPS using the VPS interface name and IP.

Below is a tutorial for modifying your gateway that I adapted from http://www.wikihow.com/Add-or-Change-the-Default-Gateway-in-Linux

Keep in mind, that if you are running a modern OS such as ubuntu, you may have NetworkManager installed and might be able to assign the gateways by editing your connections.

Remember this might be as simple as rebooting, and restarting your service. So try that as well.

If you have computers or devices connected to your computer which need access to the internet as well, then you will in fact need to implement packet filtering via iptables.

You can find a tutorial for doing this for ubuntu here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing#Gateway_set_up

**Tutorial for Setting a Linux Default Gateway**

*Adapted from http://www.wikihow.com/Add-or-Change-the-Default-Gateway-in-Linux*

> Part 1 Using the Terminal
>
> 1. Open the Terminal. You can open the Terminal from the side bar, or by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T.
> 2. View your current default gateway. You can check what your default gateway is set to by typing route and pressing ↵ Enter. The address
>      next to "default" shows your default gateway, and the interface it is
>      assigned to is displayed on the right side of the table.
> 3. Delete your current default gateway. If you have more than one default gateway set, you'll run into connection conflicts. Delete your
>      existing default gateway if you intend to change it. Type `sudo route
>      delete default gw <IP Address> <Adapter>`. For example, to delete the
>      default gateway 10.0.2.2 on the eth0 adapter, type `sudo route delete
>      default gw 10.0.2.2 eth0`.
> 4. Type `sudo route add default gw <IP Address> <Adapter>`. For example, to change the default gateway of the eth0 adapter to
>      192.168.1.254, you would type `sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.254 eth0`. You'll be prompted for your user password in order to complete
>      the command.
>
> Part 2: Editing Your Configuration File
>
> 1. Open the configuration file in an editor. Type sudo `nano /etc/network/interfaces` to open the file in the nano editor. Editing
>      your configuration file will keep your changes every time the system
>      restarts.
> 2. Navigate to the correct section. Find the section for the adapter you want to change the default gateway for. For a wired connection,
>      this is usually eth0.
> 3. Add gateway IP Address to the section. For example, type `gateway 192.168.1.254` to make the default gateway 192.168.1.254.
> 4. Save your changes and exit. Press Ctrl+X and then Y to save your changes and exit.
> 5. Restart your network. Restart your network by typing `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`